# Moment JS Parse Whole JSON Array and Format Multiple Date Instances

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, momentjs

I get an array of JSON objects back from my MVC controller and the objects have a couple of date fields I was to parse and format.

I've replaced the default MVC JSON serialiser with the excellent Newtonsoft.Json library so my dates are already fairly nicely formatted and come back like this:

```
"SystemDate": "2013-05-06T17:19:40.443",
"LocalDate": "2013-05-06T18:19:40",
```

I'm using Moment.js on the client side for my date handling and I have been looking for a neat solution to further format these dates for display in the UI.

I was about to start writing a custom function that would take a JSON array of objects with dates to format and a date pattern and an array of field names to format.

The function signature would look something like:

```
function formatDates(dataArray, pattern, fields) { /code/ };
```

dataArray would be something like:

```
[{"name": Jammer, 
  "SystemDate": "2013-05-06T17:19:40.443", 
  "LocalDate": "2013-05-06T18:19:40"
 }, 
 {another object}
 {another object} 
 {another object}
]
```

pattern would be something like:

```
"dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"
```

The list of fields would be (using the above example object):

```
[{"SystemDate"}, {"LocalDate"}]
```

I've only just started using Moment.js so I'm not particularly familiar with it's own API but from [looking at the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) there isn't anything suggesting this kind of functionality already existing in it's codebase.

Before I go off an implement this I was wondering if there was something already in Moment.js that would handle this for me?  Or any pointers on how to best implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the kind of thing that I would expect of a date manipulation library. It is really up to you to decode your data, perform iteration to find the dates, then use moments to do your date foramtting and finally, you re-encode your data back to the form that you require. That said, looking at what you want seems to be a very trivial task.

Something like this should do it for you

javascript

```
var jsonString = '[{"name":"Jammer0","SystemDate":"2013-05-06T17:19:40.443","LocalDate":"2013-05-06T18:19:40"},{"name":"Jammer1","SystemDate":"2013-05-06T17:19:40.443","LocalDate":"2013-05-06T18:19:40"},{"name":"Jammer2","SystemDate":"2013-05-06T17:19:40.443","LocalDate":"2013-05-06T18:19:40"},{"name":"Jammer3","SystemDate":"2013-05-06T17:19:40.443","LocalDate":"2013-05-06T18:19:40"}]';

var formatted = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString).map(function (record)  {
    var requiredPattern = "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a";

    record.SystemDate = moment(record.SystemDate).format(requiredPattern);
    record.LocalDate = moment(record.LocalDate).format(requiredPattern);

    return record;
}));

console.log(formatted);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/BZTEH/)

Comment: I tried adding this to my code and it generates a script error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Comment: jsFiddle really is broken.  It wont work properly even with moment.min.js referenced as an external resource.

Comment: After some playing around with the code I got this working as I wanted.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I triple checked the jsfiddle with Chromium v25, Firefox v20 and Opera v12.14, and all of them worked first time without any issue. All I can think is that you were using some old browser to test with, and here you could have problems as the above demo requires JSON and Array.map support, which you can add to older browsers by using one of the many available shims out there.

Comment: For JSON: http://www.json.org/ and for ES5: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: I was using Firefox 20 on a MacBook Pro.  I started to write my own version in jsFiddle after trying yours and had the same problem.  Even though I was specifying moment.js as an external resource from the cloudflare cdn every time I ran it it errored saying that moment was undefined.  Very odd ...